# How do I update redirect_uri param for a StackExchange App

Tags: support, api-v2.1, oauth2

I've created a StackExchange app but now I cannot find the edit page so I can update the app settings, like:

redirect_uri - which is an OAuth param

Answer (score 1):

never mind, I found the answer, https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/